# Loop through MYSQL table and perform action on row and previous row field PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I want to loop through a MySQL table, and perform a calculation based on the current row the loop is on and the previous loop.

Say my table has 2 columns - `Film_id` and `FilmRelease`, how would I loop through and echo out a calculation of the current `FilmRelease` and the previous row's column value?

Thanks guys

I have got to this stage, but for some reason it's not printing out anything

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "*****") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("*****") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT FilmRelease FROM Films_Info") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 $last_value = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

  if (!is_null($last_value)) {

    print date_diff($row['FilmRelease'], $last_value) . "<BR>";
  }

  $last_value = $row['FilmRelease'];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you should have a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$last_value = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

  if (!is_null($last_value)) {
    $interval = date_diff(new DateTime($row['FilmRelease']), new DateTime($last_value));
    echo $interval->format('Y-m-d');
  }

  $last_value = $row['FilmRelease'];
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, i have edited my question with your code, however it isnt printing anything :S

Comment: `date_diff()` expects [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). So try it with: `print date_diff(new DateTime($row['FilmRelease']), new DateTime($last_value));`

Comment: I recieve this error Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string - the column structure type is set to date not datetime. Would that cause the issue?

Comment: Can you please do a `var_dump($row['FilmRelease'])`, to see what this returns?

Comment: outputs - string(10) "2012-04-19" string(10) "2012-04-19"

Comment: Ok I know what was wrong, I edited my answer. `date_diff()` returns a `DateInterval` object, which you need to format for printing.

Comment: It now just echo's out "Y-m-dY-m-dY-m-dY-m-dY-m-dY-m-dY-m-dY-m-d" :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10276/discussion-between-dan-lee-and-dim3nsion)